# How to avoid docker-based sql server deadlock using ruby/sequel/tinytds?

Tags: sql-server, ruby, deadlock, sequel, tiny-tds

I'm working on a server-side rails-ish project that supports configuring your choice of database, where up until now your choice was between MySql and PostgreSQL. We're trying to support MS SQL Server. If we use their docker container (https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-linux/) we get deadlock instantly, most likely caused by a call to some kind of synchronization.

I found Jeff Atwood's article at https://discourse.codinghorror.com/t/deadlocked/275 on solving deadlock in SQL Server with the `nolock` modifier, but I didn't find a way to provide that as an option to the `Sequel` connection string ("Sequel" being the Ruby ORM, not the MS product),
and in any case it looks like the interplay of the Sequel ORM and the tinytds SQL Server adapter always goes through `synchronize`.

When we run sql server in native form on an Azure box, we don't hit deadlock immediately, but we do eventually, like over the course of running two hours worth of tests. The error message states to run the command again, but given that we're using an ORM, that could happen anywhere in our code (the one point I saw in a traceback was just getting a count of rows in a table), so `retry` is not a great solution.

Has anyone else run into this? Anyone have a solution?

Comment: I'll go on the record as saying "throwing `nolock` on all of your queries is not a great strategy for avoiding deadlocks". Can you provide the deadlock xml for analysis?

Comment: First, I can't add 'nolock' because we're using an ORM that abstracts away the underlying SQL. It's just a bunch of ruby calls like  

    `Salesperson.where(name:"J B Briggs", month:"Feb").update("commission", 100).save`

No opportunity to do `nolock`. Where would the deadlock xml be?

Comment: Understood. All I'm saying is that even if you *could* follow that guidance, it's bad for a lot of reasons. As for the deadlock graph, if you're on anything SQL 2008 and above, you should be able to set up an extended events session to capture it.